# Current sensing with AD623

Tags: current, current-measurement, sensing

I want to measure current that flows from a several kΩ load with source voltage sweeps from 0-200V. I want to measure possible energy losses, so I need both low and high side sensing. Setup is described in the picture. Do you think this is accurate, would 200V damage the [AD623](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD623.pdf)? And also I am not sure that where to connect Vref, so I connected it to ground.

[image: current sensing setup]

Comment: You are making two measurements of the same current ?

Comment: The top AD623 is going to die. Why would there be any loss of current between top and bottom of load?

Comment: The only way there could be current losses is if there is another load which bypasses the current sense circuit. Power losses are not the same as current losses. It is not possible for two elements in series to have different currents. If that was possible, then all the tools of circuit analysis would not work.

Comment: Thanks! But actually there probably be. Because the load will be a SiO2 wafer and other terminals are connected to it also. So probably there will be current leakage and we also want to measure it. But I didn't know the power loss and current loss are not be same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to measure the "leaking" current, then you can use a current transducer from LEM (or similar), you put both wires in, so their magnetic fields cancells each other. If the heater will leak, you will get the exact leaking current.